# Data usage + application data usage

Tags: android, network-traffic

I have done one Android application for getting total data usage and each application data usage every 24 hours once.

Application data usage:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
long recv = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uID);
long sent = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uID);
```

Total Data Usage:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
ong recv = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
long sent = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
```

But, the summation of data usage reported by the 'App Usage' is greater than overall 'total dataUsage' values.

What is the exact reason/problem here?

Answer (score 1):

From a comment in the page linked below:

> [TrafficStats.getUid..Bytes] logs more than the data transferred over the network interface.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20971

Additionally, if you do an issue search on 'TrafficStats' you may notice that as time goes by developers are losing the ability to accurately monitor data usage.

I have been greatly frustrated by this handicap.